# Formatting currency value with javascript toLocaleString rounding in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to format a currency value:

```
console.log(123123132778339.40.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD'
}))
```

The output in IE 11 returns `123123132778339`, where as, it displays `123123132778339.40` in Chrome. Seems like, this happens only for large values.

Any thoughts on what could be the issue?

Comment: I get `$123,123,132,778,339.00` in IE11, and `$123,123,132,778,339.40` in Chrome.

Comment: use `minimumSignificantDigits: 2,`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz That won't help.

Comment: `Any thoughts on what could be the issue?`  Yes, IE11 is just a load of garbage.  Another option is just to use `.toFixed(2)` if locale support is not important.  This is obviously a bug with IE11, and never likely to be fixed.

Comment: Just tested that number with a 3rd party lib called numeral.js,. -> http://numeraljs.com/  `numeral(123123132778339.40).format("$0,0.00")
` = `"$123,123,132,778,339.40"` in IE11,.  So that's an option.